# How to pass a parameter of type external from C to Fortran

Tags: c, parameters, fortran

Suppose I have the following subroutine in Fortran

```
    subroutine exec(routine)

        implicit none

        external     :: routine
        real(kind=8) :: res

        call routine(2.0d0, res)
        print *, "Fortran Result: res = ", res

    end subroutine exec
```

This subroutine receives, as an argument, an external routine. Now, suppose that this routine is written in C, and that I need to call the Fortran routine **exec** from C as well. Just like this:

```
    void op(double x, double *f) {
        *f = pow(x, 2);
    }

    void main() {
        exec_(op);
    }
```

I know that, if instead of passing an external subroutine I was passing an integer, or a double, or another conventional type, it would work, but this code returns segmentation fault. Is there any way to pass a parameter of type *external* from C to Fortran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works,you must use pointers:

```
void op(double *x, double *f) {
    *f = pow(*x, 2);
}

void main() {
    exec_(&op);
}

subroutine exec(routine)

    implicit none

    external     :: routine
    real(kind(1.d0)) :: res

    call routine(2.0d0, res)
    print *, "Fortran Result: res = ", res

end subroutine exec
```

Do not use `kind=8` it does not declare 8 byte real, but a processor dependent type with kind number 8. Even the old and nonstandard `real*8` would be better.

But it would be better to use Fortran 2003 c interoperability and the `iso_c_binding` module:

f.f90

> subroutine exec(routine_c) bind(C,name="exec_")
>       use iso_c_binding
>       implicit none
>
> ```
>     abstract interface
>         subroutine sub(a,b) bind(C)
>           use iso_c_binding
>           implicit none
>           real(c_double),value :: a
>           real(c_double) :: b
>         end subroutine
>     end interface
>
> type(c_funptr),value :: routine_c
> real(c_double) :: res
> procedure(sub),pointer :: routine
>
> call c_f_procpointer(routine_c,routine)
>
> call routine(2.0d0, res)
> print *, "Fortran Result: res = ", res
> ```
>
> end subroutine exec

c.c

```
#include <math.h>
void op(double x, double *f) {
    *f = pow(x, 2.0);
}

int main() {
    extern void exec_(void (*) (double, double *));
    exec_(&op);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation:

```
 gfortran c.c f.f90 -Wall -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fbacktrace’ is valid for Fortran but not for C [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fcheck=all’ is valid for Fortran but not for C [enabled by default]
 ./a.out 
 Fortran Result: res =    4.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful. But I tried the second code (using Fortran 2003 interoperability) and it didn't work, I got a segmentation fault error in the line calling "routine" procedure. The questions are: (1) The "function" in the abstract interface should be a "subroutine" interfacing the "op" C procedure? (2) What is real(c_double) :: getIterFunc? Shouldn't I declare, instead of this, the parameters a and b?

Comment: Yes, the C code I have the same you posted (using pointers in the arguments). In the Fortran code, I had to change a couple of things: (1) In the interface, `function` to `subroutine` (otherwise, I got a compilation error `'routine' has a type, which is not consistent with the CALL` (2) In the interface, `import :: c_funptr` to `import :: c_double` (3) `call c_f_procptr` to `call c_f_procpointer`. I also tried using the `value` modifier with `a` (and changed the attribute in C routine to a non-pointer), but the error persists.

Comment: OK, see the final version. It compiles and runs.